# Why after using animate or fadeIn, all the URL's outline all the way from the left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When i don't use fadeIn or animate, it doesn't do this.. This only happens when i use these functions (anywhere else on the page)..

What exactly happens is..

all `<a href>` tags (with text-indent:-9999px) outline (active outline) all the way from the left of the page up to the `<a>` tag, instead of just outlining the `<a>` tag by itself.

I guess it may be due to the text-indent, but it doesn't do this when i don't use the fadeIn / animate functions..  How do you get rid of this?

I hope someone knows what i'm talking about..

Comment: Can you show a jsFiddle example of what you're talking about?

Comment: I think you can hide this by using CSS and setting outline on that property to none. Or maybe try to set outline to none using the .CSS() property during animation.